# xero sdk: line item unit price rounding to 2 decimal place

Tags: xero-api

I have posted invoice in xero & passing data in 4 decimal points of unit price but xero is converting it into 2 decimal points, so i am getting total amount issue due to rounding...
Through API I know unitdp=4 have to pass but how to do same thing with sdks?

```
                LineItem qboln = new LineItem();
                qboln.Description = "Desc"
                qboln.Quantity = 3385;
                qboln.UnitAmount = 0.7550;
                qboln.AccountCode = code;             
                qboln.TaxType = "INPUT";
                qboln.TaxAmount = 0.678;
                inv.LineItems.Add(qboln);
```

so here xero is rounding unit price into 0.76 so I am getting total amount issue that is different with my original invoice.
Please tell me how to solve it ?